# Windows - How to make your own custom Theme?

Tags: windows

How can I make my own custom Windows Theme and .MSSTYLE file from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the right forum for what you are asking. If you have tried some things and are running into issues you can post what you have tried and the problems you have run into and we will try and help. If you are just getting started, maybe try taking a look at this:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24609/create-a-windows-7-theme-pack-from-scratch/